# Mildly destroying all worldly cardinals below an inaccessible by forcing

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

We call a cardinal $\theta$ worldly if $V_\theta \models \mathsf{ZFC}$. If $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, then we have an unbounded set of worldly cardinals below $\kappa$, in fact  even a club set (by considering a chain of elementary submodels of $V_\kappa$).

My question is whether it is possible to destroy the worldly cardinals below an inaccessible cardinal by forcing in a mild way in the following sense: given an inaccessible $\kappa$ can there be a forcing that destroys the worldliness of all worldly cardinals below $\kappa$ while preserving the worldliness of $\kappa$ itself?

Of course some further assumptions will be necessary, since such a forcing must singularize $\kappa$, which implies that $\kappa$ is measurable in some inner model, but I am just asking whether the existence of such a forcing is consistent relative to any appropriate large cardinal assumption.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/a/130028/1946.

Comment: Thank you, Joel, for pointing to this question. I was aware of it and your answer, but have thought about it again. However, it seems that your method of destroying a worldly cardinal really depends on it being of countable cofinality in the ground model (and therefore also in the generic extension). I actually do not know under which circumstances we can even expect to be able to change the cofinalities of a club of singular cardinals below an inaccessible $\kappa$ to $\omega$ without destroying the worldliness of  $\kappa$ or even collapsing it.

Comment: Yes, it seems difficult. I've been pondering your question over the past few days. One idea I had was like this: start with $\kappa$ measurable and add a Prikry sequence $\kappa_n$. Now, work just between each interval $[\kappa_n,\kappa_{n+1})$ to kill worldly cardinals, e.g. by making them all only $\Sigma_n$-worldly in that interval. But at the same time, try to preserve $V_{\kappa_n}\prec_{\Sigma_n}V_\kappa$. That will hide the sequence and perhaps allow you to keep $\kappa$ worldly, while destroying the ones below. But so far, I haven't managed to fit it all together.

Comment: I've just had another idea for a new strategy, however, which seems to be working. I'll post tonight---I've got to teach right now.

Comment: Well, I have several ideas, but they don't yet fully work, but they seem promising.  Alexander, let's work on this when you're in New York next month!

Comment: I would be glad to work on this problem with you during my visit to New York!

Comment: @Joel: If I had to guess, I'd guess that one measurable is not enough, and maybe something a bit larger is necessary. Of course, I have no ideas to back this intuition up.

Comment: @Joel: Here's a strategy, start with a measurable $\kappa$ such that $o(\kappa)=\kappa$, and add a $\kappa$-club using Magidor forcing, this changes the cofinality of $\kappa$ to be $\omega$, while adding a full length club. Now fix a cofinal $\omega$ sequence, and through the Magidor club (wlog, made of all the worldly cardinals) either collapse the regular cardinals, or destroy their worldliness to be only $\Sigma_n$ worldly if they are larger than the $n$th cardinal of the $\omega$ sequence. Maybe this requires some more work, but it's a semi-off hand idea.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, since it seems to destroy replacement in $V_\kappa$ of the extension, as being $\Sigma_n$ worldly is expressible (and $\Delta_2$). But I have been thinking along similar lines. I know how to reduce to the case of having only cofinality omega worldly cardinals, from just a measurable, by Prikry forcing and finding a club set $V_\kappa$-generic avoiding the uncountable cofinality worldly cardinals, and then forcing to make the new continuum function jump over those elements, making all worldly cardinals up to and including $\kappa$ have cofinality omega.

Comment: @Joel: Could you please say a bit about how you get the club set avoiding the worldly cardinals of uncountable cofinality in your construction?