# Why does the second smallest worldly cardinal believe the smallest worldly cardinal is worldly?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals

It is known that the property of being a worldly cardinal is not absolute (a cardinal $\kappa$ is worldly iff $V_{\kappa} \vDash \textsf{ZFC}$). See [here](http://jdh.hamkins.org/worldly-cardinals-are-not-always-downwards-absolute/) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130019/forcing-mildly-over-a-worldly-cardinal) for more.

This said, it is the case that the existence of two worldly cardinals has strictly greater consistency strength than the existence of one worldly cardinal, and any proof I can see of this will require that if $\kappa_1 < \kappa_2$ are worldly cardinals, then $V_{\kappa_2}$ must believe $\kappa_1$ is worldly. (Easiest proof: show that $V_{\kappa_2}$ believes that $V_{\kappa_1} \vDash \textsf{ZFC}$.)

I wasn’t sure how to show that this was the case — I was thinking that maybe because $V_{\kappa_2}$ is transitive it must agree with $V$ on whether $V_{\kappa_1}$ models $\textsf{ZFC}$, but I’m not totally clear on/sure of this.

Comment: What sort of obstacle do you see?

Comment: I think this goes as follows: Worldliness does relativize to L, and worldliness over L is absolute. But I haven't worked it out. (My bedtime was about 30 minutes ago.)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I've addressed your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The truth of a first-order sentence $\varphi$ in a structure $\mathfrak{M}$ is absolute between $V$ (= reality) and sufficiently large transitive sets containing $\mathfrak{M}$. In particular, already $V_{\kappa+2}$ correctly computes the full first-order theory of $V_\kappa$ for each infinite ordinal $\kappa$, and even that is overkill. The key point is that truth of a first-order sentence in a structure is witnessed by an appropriate family of Skolem functions, and the relevant properties are all low-complexity.

Since $\kappa_2>\kappa_1+2$, the result follows.

(This is treated in more detail in Barwise's book *Admissible sets and structures*, if memory serves, but there really are no hidden surprises.)

---

EDIT (addressing Francois' comment above): It's also true that worldliness relativizes downwards to (but not necessarily upwards from!) $L$, but this isn't actually related to the above. The issue is "worldliness-in-$L$" is a property of $V_\kappa^L$ (which for reasonably closed $\kappa$ is just $L_\kappa$), not of the genuine $V_\kappa$ ($=V_\kappa^V$ if you like) considered inside $L$. So the key fact is Godel's theorem that if $V_\kappa\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ then $L_\kappa\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. But this actually involves a nontrivial analysis of $L$. And the general failure of *upwards* absoluteness ruins any hope of an application the other way.

(To see that worldliness need not be absolute upwards from $L$, consider what happens if $\kappa$ is worldly in $L$ but countable in $V$ - which can happen, e.g. by forcing over $L$ with $Col(\omega,\kappa)$.)

Comment: Thanks Noah that's exactly what I needed